# SQL 2008 Composite Primary Key With One Part of the Key Auto Increment

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, primary-key

Simple table with composite primary key.
`PK1 smallint, PK2 smallint auto increment, strValue varchar(20) not null.`

This works but PK2 increments independent of PK1.

What I would like is for PK2 to start fresh with a fresh PK1.

Here is what I get

```
    1, 1, 1a
    1, 2, 1b
    2, 3, 2a
    2, 4, 2b
```

What I want

```
    1, 1, 1a
    1, 2, 1b
    2, 1, 2a
    2, 2, 2b
```

I take it I need to remove the auto increment from PK2 and generate the proper value on the Insert statement?  Is that the correct way to get there and do you recommend syntax for the Insert statement?  Auto increment PK1 is not an option as it is part of FK relationship.

Assume I need to insert 2, x, 3b and need to know what value was assigned for x.
There are NOT going to be a lot of inserts (like 100 / day). 
There is a unique constraint on PK1, strValue.

To be clear I think SQL 2008 is doing the right thing and am not suggesting that SQL should behave this way by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not doing a lot of inserts to the table you can probably remove the identity column and simply do:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE PK1 = 2 AND strValue = '3b' )
BEGIN
  DECLARE @next_PK2 INT

  SELECT
    @next_PK2 = ISNULL(MAX(PK2) + 1, 0) + 1
  FROM
    table
  WHERE
    PK1 = 2

  INSERT table VALUES (2, @next_PK2, '3b')
END
```

Comment: Would it not be (ISNULL(MAX(PK2), 0) + 1 ?  And strValue = '3b' is not in the table yet.   Actually if there is already a '3b' I need to abort the insert as it will violate the unique constraint.  If I put it all in a transaction would that take care of the rare chance of two simultaneous inserts of 2,x,3b?  Should I put a tablock hint on the insert?

Comment: But you did not take out the AND strValue = '3b'.  Clean it up and I will give you the check.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to control the incremental value of PK2 you need to generate that during insert (such as with a `ROW_NUMBER()`. There isn't any other way to set the PK2 independently.

Comment: And be very careful to handle race conditions

Comment: I just not seeing how ROW_NUMBER() is the answer?  Assume I want to insert 2, x, 2c.

Comment: @HLGEM Exactly. Data integrity is everything on this.  There will NOT be a lot of inserts.  I can live a TABLOCK if necessary.  Looking for a rock solid insert.  I can live with auto increment on PK2 if necessary.

Comment: @BalamBalam, are you doing batch inserts, or one row at a time. If it's one row at a time, then either live with the autoincrement or increment the next value yourself. If they are batch inserts, then you could use row_number() to increment the value of PK2 during the insert.

Comment: Individual rows. When I look up row_number() I see it used in partitions and that does not seem to be what I need.

Comment: @BalamBalam, not table partitions just to partition the query. So in your example of what you wanted, if it were one batch using ROW_NUMBER() to generate PK2 would result in exactly what you wanted. Since you are doing single inserts, then the IDENTITY column on PK2 being out of sync with the sets in PK1 or controlling the value of PK2 during INSERT are your only choices.